# Flutter Image AppBar Extend further than background

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

My question is how do I extend my transparent image further than the appbar's borders? I want the image to cover the whole of the appbar, I have tried using fit: and it doesn't do the job. I want the whole of the orange covered by the image.

This is my code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var title = 'Web Images';

return MaterialApp(
  title: title,
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: SizedBox(
        width: 1000,
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/foodBackground.png'),


         ),
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xffFA7343),
        ),
        body: Text('test1'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[This is the image of how it looks, as you can see it hasn't filled to the edges of the appbar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMzwc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this and you need to ensure `titleSpacing` should be zero and you dynamic width `ouble.infinity`

```
AppBar(
          titleSpacing: 0,
          title: SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/test.jpg'),
          ),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffFA7343),
        )
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
AppBar(
  flexibleSpace: Image.asset(
    'assets/images/foodBackground.png',
  ),
),
```